# uninitialized constant UController::User_param

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am making a basic account setup and to try to learn how the database stuff works. I have been running into this error constantly, and I have no idea how to make it disappear.  I have my stuff named as U, so the URL will be easier to type a username like Reddit has it `example.com/u/username`

The Error is `uninitialized constant UController::User_param`

It highlights this code: `@user = U.new(User_param)`

**Controller:**

```
class UController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @users = U.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def create
    @user = U.new(User_param)

    if @user.save
      redirect_to :action => 'list'
    else
      @user = U.all
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end

  def User_param
    params.require(:Us).permit(:id, :email, :password, :created_at, :updated_at)
  end

  def new
    @user = U.new
  end

  def edit
  end
end
```

**Routes:**
`resources :u`

**U Model:**

```
class U < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Rails you don't capitalize methods, only constants and classes. change `User_param` to `user_params` along with the method and that should work. I made params plural since it is clearer and easier to understand

Also, change the user_param method to this:

```
def user_params
  params.require(:u).permit(:id, :email, :password, :created_at, :updated_at)
end
```

The `.require(:u)` doesn't need to be plural as you had it.

Comment: It seems to have worked, but how would I check inside the MySQL table to make sure it entered the data inside?  I've done this `mysql> SELECT * FROM U;
Empty set (0.00 sec)`  I don't think it actually saved it.

Comment: the best route is to use the rails console. Literally type 'rails console' into the command line or use 'rails console --sandbox' if you don't want to make any changes. From there simply type 'U.all'

Comment: I have done some fixes to make it so it appears in the rails console, I got the email working but not the password.  It says `undefined method `permit' for "password i typed":String Did you mean? print`.  It highlighted this `params.require(:u).permit(:id, :email, :password, :created_at, :updated_at)`

Comment: I can't understand what you've written. Can you edit it and reply?

Comment: rewrite it in a new comment for me